# Why do different unit parameters for `du` give conflicting results?

Tags: linux, disk-space

I get this output when checking the total amount of space I'm using on my Walkman.

```
david@Milton:/media$ du -b --max-depth=0 WALKMAN/
14823290693 WALKMAN/
david@Milton:/media$ du -k --max-depth=0 WALKMAN/
14523776    WALKMAN/
```

Last I checked, `14,523,776 KB * 1024 = 14,872,646,624 B`, not `14,823,290,693 B`. Dividing the two, their "K" unit seems to be equal to about `1020.62` rather than `1024` as advertised. This is causing some errors in the program I wrote to sync my Walkman, so it fills up faster than it claims to. Can anyone explain this discrepancy?

Answer (score 3):

du -b is described in the help documentation (du --help) as:

```
  -b, --bytes           equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1'
```

where

```
      --apparent-size   print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although
                      the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be
                      larger due to holes in (`sparse') files, internal
                      fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
```

du -k, by contrast, provides

```
  -k                    'like --block-size=1K'
```

That is, du -k gives the disk usage of the file, while du -b gives the 'apparent size' of the file. The apparent size is usually (but not always) smaller.

(Source: [coreutils bug report](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2006-10/msg00281.html)).

Comment: And if you’re checking the disk usage on your walkman, you almost certainly don’t want the apparent size but the actual size.